# Time Series Intervention Analysis with armax function

Tags: time-series, arima, intervention-analysis

My aim is to quantify the effect of an intervention on a time series of outcome-measures. For that, I tried to follow this blog post: 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/time-series-intervention-analysis-wih-r-and-sas/

This is the dependent time series

```
rate <- ts(c(7.41,  6.75,  6.09,  6.27,  7.29,  7.08,  6.76,  6.40,  7.90, 10.47, 10.46, 11.89, 12.42, 12.95,
            12.35, 14.26, 14.62, 15.09, 13.46, 13.02, 13.77, 11.84, 13.50, 15.80), start = 1)

plot(rate)
```

I tried to identify the arima processes and estimated the model. As it is yearly data, I am not assuming any seasonality.

```
acf(rate)
pacf(rate)

auto.arima(rate)

mod.1 <- arima(rate, order = c(0,1,0))
```

As I am assuming a step change (from a theoretical point of view), I created a step transfer function. The Intervention happens after 11 years:

```
intervention <- structure(list(step = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 )), .Names = "consent", row.names = c(NA,-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now when it comes to estimating the intervention analysis, I am struggling, especially because I am not entirely sure I understand the components of the arimax function.

```
mod.2 <- arimax(rate, order=c(0,1,0), xtransf= intervention, transfer=list(c(1,0)))
```

gives me the following error:

```
Error in stats::arima(x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, fixed = par[1:narma],  : 
  wrong length for 'fixed'
```

1. Where does the error come from?
2. What does the transfer=list(c(1,0)) part specify?
3. I am also not entirely sure how to interpret the outcome: What information quantifies the effect the intervention had on the dependent variable?
4. Could I add other possible confounding variables through xreg?

And one general question: Are there enough data points to justify this type of analysis?

Thank you very much!